# soapui junk text in log display

Tags: soapui

Soapui junk text
[image]

TcpMon junk text
[image]

I have a mock process of type http post, which just echo the payload as it is.

client-->tcpMon-->soapuiMock-->tcpMon-->client is the flow

in the above flow the response from sopui mock is showing as junk text which in turn tcpmon response is showing as junk and in client its showing properly.

How can I introspect the response in both soapui and tcpmon response area properly?

Using soapui in linux envronment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot mentions gzip compression, and it looks like that data is gzip compressed. I tried compressing "something" on my terminal and see the response.

```
$ echo "something" | gzip -f
S�"W+��M-���K�6��
```

So, for your mock, you need to apply gunzip.

Comment: @ user1886721 Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in soapui mock editor **onRequestScript** tab paste the below code it will solve the issue.

```
headers = mockRequest.requestHeaders;
headers.remove("Accept-Encoding");
```

along with that i have unchecked a soapui configuration element

> soapui-->preferences-->http settings--> response compression

Thanks

Comment: If that resolved the issue, you can accept it as answered.